# How do I add a 'TAB' feature in my custom wysiwyg editor?

Tags: javascript, html

By tab I mean lots of space, so, when I write in the editor, I'd like to be able to hit the tab button on the keyboard and gets spaces instead of switching between elements.

Comment: What editor are you talking about?  There are about a zillion.

Comment: Note that I'm referring to web programming

Comment: If you're on Windows, you can probably go 'Help' -> 'About', and it will tell you the name of the application you are using. If you are on a Mac, look in the top left, and the name of the program will probably be there. Without this info, there is nothing we can do to help.

Comment: Similar to TinyMCE editor but plus a tab feature, if I'm not mistaken, the editor in yahoo mails has that tab feature

Comment: We can't help with something that's 'similar to TinyMCE' - we need to know exactly what it is. Maybe http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=813 will help

Comment: Sorry for my vague question :p

Comment: Without knowing your editor, I can't tell you whether or not there is a setting that you can change. All I can suggest is writing a bit of JavaScript that will respond to the keypress event - check whether it's the 'tab' key that has been pressed, and return false if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins that does this for tab character. Here's [one](http://teddevito.com/demos/textarea.html) that is pretty comprehensive. If you just want some code you can insert into your script, I wrote something simple.

```
var shift = false;
function codebox(element) {

    element.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 16)
            shift = false;
    });

    element.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) { 
        if (event.keyCode == 16) {
            shift = true;
            return;
        }

        if (event.keyCode == 9) {
            var start = this.selectionStart;
            var end = this.selectionEnd;
            var lead = this.value.substr(0, start);
            var chunk = this.value.substr(start, end - start);

            if (!shift) {
                if (start == end)
                    lead = lead + "\t";
                else {
                    lead = ("\n" + lead).split("").reverse().join("").replace(/\n/, "\t\n").split("").reverse().join("").substr(1);
                    chunk = chunk.replace(/\n/g, "\n\t");
                    if (chunk.substr(-2) == "\n\t")
                        chunk = chunk.substr(0, chunk.length - 1);
                }
            } else {
                if (chunk.split("")[0] == "\t") {
                    lead = lead + "\t";
                    chunk = chunk.substr(1);
                }
                lead = ("\n" + lead).split("").reverse().join("").replace(/\t\n/, "\n").split("").reverse().join("").substr(1);
                chunk = chunk.replace(/\n\t/g, "\n");
            }

            this.value = lead + chunk + this.value.substr(end);
            this.selectionStart = lead.length;
            this.selectionEnd = lead.length + chunk.length;
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}
```

To use it, simply do this:

```
new codebox(myTextAreaElement);
```

Since you want spaces, wrap the event handlers with a procedure to convert between spaces and tabs.